# Combobox dont show correctly text on tab

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, combobox, tabs

I have the following problem with `ComboBox` (DropDownList). My settings for combo:

```
AutoCompleteMode: AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
AutoCompleteSource: AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
DropDownStyle: ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

This combobox have datasource from database.

```
`DisplayMember = "nombre";
 ValueMember = "id";`
```

Now reproduction steps:

Focus and Popup (!) `ComboBox`, type for example 'dog' (at first element is selected 'ant' is selected, then 'dog' - which is fine) and then press Tab - Random value 'turtle' or anything is restored... no events of the value or index changed fired.. While debugging I see that on `combobox Leave event` value is still 'dog', but on `DropDownClosed` event it's switched back to 'turtle'. Nothing is fired in between.

I can´t understand why the combobox change text randomly but in debug mode still correctly.

I need when tab using autocomplete feature, the combobox still on value and text when im press tab.

PD: this happen only in combobox with datasource from database and the other computer LOL. in my workstation it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2868238/en-us

It's O.S error, for previous versions of windows 7 SP1.